# Where is c# 7.2 in visual studio project settings?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, project-settings, c#-7.2

Ive seen people using and discussing c# 7.2 features but I cant seem to find it.

Ive got latest updates and only up to version `7.1` is listed. why and how can I get v7.2?

[image]

---

specs:

Visual studio 2017 version 15.4.4

Visual C# 2017 - 00369-60000-00001-AA303

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Version 15.4.* of VS 2017 doesn't support C# 7.2.

C# 7.2 support was introduced in VS 2017 version 15.5, [which was released on December 4th](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#15.5).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, does that mean c# 7.2 it self is in preview and is prone to changes?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary: Well, I don't know of any non-preview release of the compiler - but I think it's so *close* to release that I'd be very surprised if it changed at this point.

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5 was [released](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#15.5) on December 4th.