# Can I modify the value type object from within the extension method it is calling?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Lets say we have the following function:

```
public static void AddTo(this int inInt, int inAmountToAdd)
{
    inInt += inAmountToAdd;
}
```

This will simply modify the parameter value "inInt".

Can I somehow get a reference to the value type object calling this static extension method in order to modify it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C# 7.2, ref extension methods are allowed. This was not allowed in prior versions. You would have to declare the method like this:

```
public static void AddTo(this ref int inInt, int inAmountToAdd)
{
    inInt += inAmountToAdd;
}
```

And then also use VS 2017 (requires version 15.5 or newer) with the [language version set to 7.2 (or latest)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47328622/517852).

Note that when you use this feature, the caller must call the method with something that can act as ref in the receiver position (i.e. a field, local variable, or array slot). If you were planning on using this in some kind fluent API, it might not work as expected. For example, this would fail to compile: `GetInt().AddTo(1)` because the return value of the method GetInt is not a valid `ref`.

Note the above syntax might require 15.6 as per [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1022) but the feature should be available in 15.5 using `ref this` if I am reading this correctly.

Comment: Do you have a link to where I can read up on this? I searched but wasn't able to find it in the "What is new in C# 7.2". I found a bunch of feature requests, but not anywhere showing that it was completed and included.

Comment: @Cory The [c# language repo](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang) is good place to look. I found this [item](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/38370edf77e23da6c459bfbdf7c36dacd14eea7f/proposals/csharp-7.2/readonly-ref.md) which made me think it was not fully implemented, but i tried it on [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/) which allows you to run very recent (nightly?) compiler builds and it worked. So I tried it in a somewhat up to date VS 2017 and it provided helpful error messages about enabling 7.2.